# Trigger a 555 with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, 555

I need to use a 555 timer to generate a delayed pulse when the Arduino triggers the timer. I am not sure if this can be done this way: I would connect the 555 timer’s pin 2 to an Arduino’s digital pin.

The code would use three `digitalWrite()`s to change the voltage from HIGH to LOW and then again to HIGH, but I am not sure if doing this could damage the 555 timer.

Comment: Probably not.  It depends on the Arduino output high and low voltages, and the power supply voltage for the 555.

Comment: You can delay any pulse with the same voltage , polarity with 2 of 6 inverters or Schmitt inverters and an RC delay or a counter delay or change the Arduino code to add delay.  A 555 might also be possible with 5V

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have the Arduino send out a pulse when you actually want it, instead of sending it prematurely, then delaying it with the 555?